# Interview challenge implementing binary semaphore with given functions

Tags: multithreading

I have been asked in a job interview how to implement a fair lock when dealing with multi-threading programing.

For this task I have been given 5 function to use:

```
// those 2 first functions are atomic.
bool test_and_set(struct *lock)
{
    int temp=lock->value;
    lock->value=1;
    return temp==1;
}

void reset(struct *lock)
{
   lock->value=0;
}
```

- `sleep (int x)` - this function can delay the thread for x sec, note x can be infinity.
- `signal (thread id)` - this function can wake up thread number id.
- `getid()` - returns the thread id.

Comment: What was your proposed solution?

Comment: The `reset` function doesn't make sense to me

Comment: what programming language is this? Q2. is test&set an identifier!? Q3. if guard is global wouldn't it be shadowed by local declaration of guard in your example functions?? (if this is C like language)

Comment: Do you have a specific question relating to how to solve the problem? If you don't have a specific question, then Stackoverflow is probably not the right place to ask. Nobody is going to solve this puzzle for you and post the answer here. Try to solve it yourself and post new questions for any problems you encounter. If you need feedback for your solution, you might also want to look at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If there's a written part for your interview, don't do it all in lower case `:)`.